# Is there a way to page down in the tree in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Do I really have to keep pressing down and up and only going 1 line at a time in NERDTree?  Is there a way to page down or search for files?  My tree structure is pretty big and it's a bit of a pain to traverse that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard movement controls apply. So you could use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to move down a page at a time (and the reverse <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to move a page up at a time).

To search for a directory or file you can use the standard <kbd>/</kbd> + [search-pattern].

Comment: Thanks!  I should have guessed that.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal split window so you can use standard vim shortcuts:

```
Ctrl-D  "move half-page down
Ctrl-U  "move half-page up
Ctrl-B  "page up
Ctrl-F  "page down
```